# Find text in a file and print the text 3 lines before it after the word CHOICE

Tags: perl

I have a directory with multiple files in it and will be looking for a text pattern in the file.  Once I find the text I need to get the text that is 3 lines above it after the work CHOICE. For example below is 4 lines from one file.  I want to be able search for the text "intl_reg.jcl" find the below and get the 3rd line up text "registered international students with balances". The word CHOICE will always be in front of the text I need.

CHOICE List registered international students with balances
SHORTCUT 8
PROCESS CHDIR /d3/locban/arsys
PROCESS CMD ksh /d3/locban/arsys/intl_reg.jcl

The output would show the searched for text and then the 3rd line up text after the word CHOICE. Output example below:

intl_reg.jcl List registered international students with balances

I am new to PERL so I wasn't sure how to begin to do this.  Explanation as well as answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sliding window:

```
perl -ne '
    print $buffer[0] if /intl_reg\.jcl/ && @buffer > 2;
    push @buffer, $_;
    shift @buffer if @buffer > 3;
' -- file1 file2 ...
```

Or you can remember the line containing CHOICE and check three lines later whether `intl_reg.jcl` is present:

```
perl -ne '
    $s = $_, $n = $. if /CHOICE/;
    print $s if /intl_reg\.jcl/ && $n && $. == $n + 3;
    $. = 0 if eof;
' -- file1 file2 ...
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
- `$_` contains the current input line;
- `$.` contains the current input line number;
- Restarting `$.` is needed for multiple files, otherwise the CHOICE line could have come from a previous file.